# Finding 4-dimensional minimum (a,b,c,d) of the integral of a function I(a,b,c,d)

Tags: python, integration, minimization

I have a nasty discontinuous 2 dimensional integral `I(k,k''; J,Jp,a,b,c,d)` that has 4 variational parameters `(a,b,c,d)` and 2 fixed constants `(J,Jp)`. The procedure to finding the integral isn't straightforward and has a first step.

1. I need to find the root (`mu`) to a one-dimensional integral from `-pi`
   to `pi`

   `A = Integrate [ 1/(exp(E(k; a,b,c,d)-mu)+1 ] dk/2pi = 0.5`,

   where `E` is a complicated function consisting of square roots and cosines.
2. Having found mu, I need to find the 4D (global) minimum `(a,b,c,d)` values to this two-dimensional integral (same `-pi` to `pi` limits) with `J`, `Jp` supplied.

   `result(J,Jp) = Minimum[ Integrate [ I(J,Jp;k,k''; a,b,c,d,mu) ] dk/2pi dk''/2pi ]`

The complicated function `I` basically looks like

```
I(J,Jp;k,k''; a,b,c,d,mu) = A(k)*A(k'')*f(a,b,c,d)*[J cos(k+k'') + Jp cos(k-k'')]
```

I have done the first step to finding `mu` with assumed values of `a,b,c,d`, but am unsure how to go about with arbitrary values of them. Is there another way besides nesting all the lambda functions? Even so, how do I go about nesting lambda functions to accomplish what I need?

```
beta=100.0
a=1.2
b=1.5
c=0.1
d=0.5
findmu = lambda mu: integrate.quad(lambda k:1.0/(2.0*pi)*1.0/(exp(beta*(0.5*(c+d-2.0*(1.0+b)*cos(k)-sqrt(32.0*(b*cos(k/2.0))**2.0+(c-d-2.0*(1-b)*cos(k))**2.0))-mu))+1.0)-0.5/(2.0*pi), -pi,pi)
mu0 = optimize.fsolve(findmu,0.0)
```

I have the procedure written in Mathematica, but it's taking too long to obtain the minimum, and are sometimes wrong. I would like to try porting it over to Python, which I am currently learning. Thanks!

EDIT: More information on the physical system: The first step is finding the Fermi level of a quantum system by imposing the filling of the system. With the Fermi level, one can find what variational parameters minimize the ground state energy of this Hartree-Fock system.

Comment: (1) Could you give both of the equations?  I think I can see what E is -- and I think you're missing a ) from your findmu line -- but (2) it looks like E will sometimes be complex.  Is that correct?

Comment: E could sometimes be complex, but the 1st step is basically imposing a constraint such that E will not be complex. All the parameters are real too (it is in reality trying to solve a physical system). I have edited the original post to include the actual form of E. As it can be seen, it is pretty complicated. The function I need to minimize, _I_ can be thought of as squared versions of E multiplied by [ J cos(k+k'') + Jp cos(k-k'') ]

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at your equation at all, but I can give you the information on how to nest the lambdas.  You can simply add `lambda a, b, c, d:` to the front of your current lambda, then `findmu(a, b, c, d)` would return a function that you would pass into `optimize.fsolve()`, for example:

```
beta=100.0
findmu = lambda a, b, c, d: lambda mu: integrate.quad(lambda k:1.0/(2.0*pi)*1.0/(exp(beta*(0.5*(c+d-2.0*(1.0+b)*cos(k)-sqrt(32.0*(b*cos(k/2.0))**2.0+(c-d-2.0*(1-b)*cos(k))**2.0))-mu))+1.0)-0.5/(2.0*pi), -pi,pi)
mu0 = optimize.fsolve(findmu(1.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.5),0.0)
# now just tweak the values for the arguments to findmu in subsequent calls
```

This makes a closure for the values of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` that you pass into `findmu()`, it might make more sense to rename `findmu` to `make_findmu` or something similar.

It might make the code more readable to use an actual function definition rather than lambdas here:

```
def make_findmu(a, b, c, d):
    beta = 100.0
    return lambda mu: integrate.quad(lambda k:1.0/(2.0*pi)*1.0/(exp(beta*(0.5*(c+d-2.0*(1.0+b)*cos(k)-sqrt(32.0*(b*cos(k/2.0))**2.0+(c-d-2.0*(1-b)*cos(k))**2.0))-mu))+1.0)-0.5/(2.0*pi), -pi,pi)

mu0 = optimize.fsolve(make_findmu(1.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.5),0.0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will accomplish my final step of finding the minimum (I added some details to the final goal in the question). Basically the entire procedure will require finding result(J,Jp) =  minimum of a 2D integral that depends primarily on J,Jp;k,k'';a,b,c,d,mu with k and k'' being integrated out with a,b,c,d taking on values that will give me the minimum for a particular J and Jp. mu is obtained by the fsolve procedure as mentioned in the original question, and what seems to me your suggested code. Please say anything if what I wrote is confusing (it is!)